# How to increase the pagination speed

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pagination

In my project I have done a pagination using PHP,  I have done it as follows:
Each buttons(NEXT PAGE and PREVIOUS PAGE) are hyperlinks which links to the same page with passing a GET variable (PAGENUMBER). For each page change, there are scripts for

1. connect to DB .
2. query for the data for the specified page.
3. close the
4. DB connection. displays the data.

The problem is that it is working slowly. Is there any alternative method for each time connect to db and query for the data and close db connection.

Also During the pagination I want to reload only the datas from DB  and all other contents in page remains the same and dont want to reload. How to achieve this?

The script is given below

```
    <?php
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");    //include files for login system
if($fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $login=true;
}
else
{
    $login=false;
}
require_once("db.php"); 
$con=connect();     //connect to db and select the db
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE> Gallery </TITLE>
        <META name="generator" content="Adobe Photoshop(R) CS Web Photo Gallery">
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link href="images/galleryStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/new.css" />
    </HEAD>
<body  marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 leftmargin=0 topmargin=0>
<table><tr>
<?php
//////////////////DISPLAYING IMAGE THUNBNAILS//////////////////////
$query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gallery ";
$res = query($query);
$raw=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$imagecount=$raw[0];
if($imagecount==0) { die ("No images found"); }
$pagecount=ceil($imagecount/15); 
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']) : 1;
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
   if (!(ctype_digit($_GET['page']) and $_GET['page']>0 and $_GET['page']<=$pagecount))
   { 
       die ("You are not autorised to viw this page");
   }
}
$start= ($page*15)-15; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM gallery  ORDER BY imageid DESC LIMIT $start , 15";
$res = query($query);
$count= mysql_num_rows($res);
$index=0;
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
{
?>
<TR>
<?php
for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++)
{
   if(!$raw=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {break;}
   $index++;
   $imageid=$raw['imageid'];
   $thumbpath= $raw['thumbpath'];
   $largepath=$raw['largepath'];
   $caption=$raw['caption'];
?>
<A name=1 href="image.php?imageid=<?php echo $imageid ?>&imageindex=<?php echo ((($page-1)*15)+$index-1) ;  ?> "><IMG  border=0 src="<?php echo $thumbpath; ?>" height="75" width="75" alt="<?php echo $caption ?>" title="<?php echo $caption ?>" ></A><BR>
<?php
echo "<a href='delete.php?delete=yes&imageid=".$imageid.'&page='.$page."'>Delete </a>"
echo "<a href='replace.php?update=yes&imageid=".$imageid.'&page='.$page."'>Replace </a>"
?>
</table>
</td>
<?php } ?>
</TR>
<?php
} 
if ($page!=1)
{
?>
<td width=17><a href=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page-1); ?> "><IMG SRC="images/previous.gif" BORDER=0></a></td>
<?php  } ?>
<td align=middle class="pagenums"><?php echo "page ".$page." of ".$pagecount ?></td>
<?php
if ($page!=$pagecount)
{
?>
<td align=right width=17><a href=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($page+1); ?> "><img border=0 src="images/next.gif"></a></td>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may use AJAX for this. Calculate count once and use iot in your AJAX requests.

Comment: How does the query look like? How many rows in your DB? How does the code look like?

Comment: There is some useful article and discussion on the post http://www.ovaistariq.net/404/mysql-paginated-displays-how-to-kill-performance-vs-how-to-improve-performance/. Do check the suggestions at the end of the blog post.

Comment: @Thomas Potaire  only less than 1000 rows. Queries are simplest queries, only 4 columns in DB, strings,integers and path to image files in File system.Page contents are images and some captions

Comment: I mean we really need to see some code/queries if you want our help.

Comment: @ Thomas Potaire  I have added the scripts to my quesion

Answer (score 1):

There are lot much options available

1. go with javascript pagination
2. ajax pagination
3. try to reduce pagination code(optimized code)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to connect/close db for each page change

Comment: thanks for your response, how to keep the connection alive during page change. please help

Comment: Use your connection statements at top of your page, or put them in PHP file like config.php and use `include_once('config.php')`

Comment: If the connection statements are the top , they execute every time the page loading, that is for every page change

Comment: use second method with `include_once('config.php')` at top of your page

Comment: @ Amir It is happening in this method also.

Comment: I have added the scripts to my quesion

Comment: create an index on `imageid`, also if you do not need all columns, do not use `select *`...try to improve your code and reduce `if else`

Answer (score 0):

use the ajax script for connecting and getting database values with reloading the current page you can do it -- -- -- --- -- -- try ajax